# Unable to populate the drop down list options with values from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to populate a drop down list with a set of values, from 1,2,.... 100. Currently, I am doing this and its not working.

*In the head section*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var select = document.getElementById("selectAge");
    var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }​
</script>
```

And, then *in the form*, I have

```
<label>Age</label>
<select id="selectAge"> 
    <option>Select your age</option>        
</select>
```

---

The drop down is not populated with a single value. I mean, I don't understand why its not happening. One correction might be to put the java script code just before the closing `</body>` tag, as its supposed to be populated only after the DOM is loaded. But I have even tried that and it does not work.

Comment: More than likely, the `select` element hasn't been rendered yet.  Do a `console.log(select);` and see if anything  is inside of it.

Comment: I think Kyle is right, run the script when the page is fully loaded

Comment: Looks like your are using jquery in your page. Try executing this code when the document has finished loading via [$(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var selectAge = $("#selectAge"), 
        options = [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
        i;
        for ( i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            $(selectAge).append("<option value='" + options[i] + "'>" + options[i] + "</option>");
        }
    });
</script>
<body>
<lable>Age:</lable>
<select id="selectAge">
    <option>Select your age</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Works just fine in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPjGH/). If you are using jQuery, wrap the whole thing in

```
$(function() { ... your code ...})`
```

to wait until the DOM is ready.